# Running TCP server-client in mininet hosts

Tags: python, tcp, client, hosts, mininet

I am new to SDN. I am trying to run server-client python scripts in Mininet hosts. The server side is running fine on one of the hosts. However, the client (running on another host) is unable to reach the server.

Every time I get the following errors:

> Exception: [Errno 111] Connection refused

> Exception while sending data: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

I googled about this issue without finding any suitable solution.

Comment: can you share the script?

Comment: Using mininetAPI similar problem Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531181/errno-111-connection-refused-python-mininet-api-hosts-client-server-no-connect